# Problem installing Ruby 1.9.2 on Mac OS Lion

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-lion

I am running Lion, utilizing Xcode 4, have RVM and homebrew installed but am only able to run ruby 1.8.7

```
    spurvis:~ rogue$ ruby -v
    ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
    spurvis:~ rogue$
```

I've read through several threads related to this topic but nothing seems to work for my problem:

```
    spurvis:~ rogue$ rvm install 1.9.2
    Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/rogue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a     while depending on your cpu(s)...

    ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #fetching 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #extracted to /Users/rogue/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290 (already extracted)
    Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/rogue/.rvm/archives
    Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/rogue/.rvm/src
    Configuring yaml in /Users/rogue/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
    Compiling yaml in /Users/rogue/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
    Installing yaml to /Users/rogue/.rvm/usr
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #configuring 
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #compiling 
    ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /Users/rogue/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/make.log
    ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The make.log gives me the following info:

```
    [2011-08-08 11:50:52] make
    /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith  -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initial
    rbconfig.rb unchanged
    ./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r./ext/purelib.rb  ./enc/make_encmake.rb --  builtin-encs="ascii.o us_ascii.o unicode.o utf_8.
    ./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r./ext/purelib.rb  -I. ./tool/compile_prelude.rb     ./prelude.rb ./enc/prelude.rb ./gem_prelude
    /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initial
    ar rcu libruby.1.9.1-static.a dln.o encoding.o version.o array.o bignum.o class.o compar.o     complex.o dir.o dln_find.o enum.o enumera
    /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamiclib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace -install_name /Users/r
    : -w -L 'Init_*' -L '*_threadptr_*' libruby.1.9.1.dylib
    ./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r./ext/purelib.rb  ./tool/generic_erb.rb -c -o    encdb.h ./template/encdb.h.tmpl ./enc enc
    encdb.h unchanged
    make -f enc.mk RUBY="./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r./ext/purelib.rb "    MINIRUBY="./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `enc'.
    make -f enc.mk RUBY="./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r./ext/purelib.rb "  MINIRUBY="./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r./ext/purelib.rb  ./tool/generic_erb.rb -c -o  transdb.h ./template/transdb.h.tmpl ./enc/tra
    transdb.h unchanged
    make -f enc.mk RUBY="./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r./ext/purelib.rb "    MINIRUBY="./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `./enc/trans'.
make -f enc.mk RUBY="./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r./ext/purelib.rb "   MINIRUBY="./miniruby -I./lib -I.ext/common -I./- -r
    mkdir -p .ext/x86_64-darwin11.0.0/enc .ext/x86_64-darwin11.0.0/enc/trans enc enc/trans
    compiling -test-/bug-3662
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    compiling -test-/string
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    compiling bigdecimal
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    compiling continuation
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    compiling coverage
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    compiling curses
    
    compiling openssl
    /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin11.0.0 -I../.././include - I../.././ext/openssl -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"
    ossl_bio.c: In function ‘ossl_obj2bio’:
    ossl_bio.c:26: error: called object ‘".rnd"’ is not a function
    ossl_bio.c:42: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
    make[1]: *** [ossl_bio.o] Error 1
    make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

Per other suggestions I tried adding export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 to my bashrc but that didn't solve the problem either.

Please help!

Comment: Try rvm install 1.9.2 --with-gcc=clang per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the latest xcode available (you'll need to update it if you're running a copy from snow leopard. Update RVM `rvm get head` and then try again.

I had problems compiling ree but 1.9.2 worked fine, you can try adding this function to .profile in your home directory, it'll compile with gcc (instead of the default LLVM)

```
# using_gcc for 64btt compiling on lion (solves compatability issues)
function using_gcc() {
  env CC="/usr/bin/gcc-4.2" ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" ARCHS="x86_64" $*
}
```

Then run `using_gcc rvm install 1.9.2`

Comment: This worked for me. You can see whether the compiler is the problem in .rvm/log/make.log (mine had a Segfault).

`CC="/usr/bin/gcc-4.2" ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" ARCHS="x86_64" rvm install 1.9.2`

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a fresh copy of Lion & Xcode 4.2, you're going to need to install the [GCC 4.2 dev libraries](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) first - they aren't included in a fresh Xcode 4.2 install.

Then pass the `CC="/usr/bin/gcc-4.2"` flag when installing your rvm.

Be sure to `rvm remove` any previous installation attempts first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `rvm install ree` with ruby 1.8.7 to work, this solved the problem for me:

```
# using_gcc for 32btt compiling on lion (solves compatability issues)
function using_gcc() {
  env CC="/usr/bin/gcc-4.2" ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_32" ARCHS="x86_32" $*
}

#then

using_gcc rvm install ree
```

Basically just changing "64" to "32" in the other answer.