# cannot install ruby 1.9.2 on mac os x lion, gcc issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion

ERROR: The provided CC(/usr/bin/gcc) is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read rvm requirements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985690/problem-installing-ruby-1-9-2-on-mac-os-lion

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking out [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) and the [GCC installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) for Mac OS X. Remember to install GCC before installing any Rubys!